# Android Activity with Transparent Layout

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view, android-dialog

I wish to create a activity that look like a popup window

That is with transparent background for activity als i wish to show it in custom position on scree that is on right corner of device  screen

what i did was inside `onCreate` of pop over like activty

```
Display display = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    // params.x = -20;
    params.height = (display.getHeight()) / 2;
    params.width = (display.getWidth()) / 2;
    // params.y = -10;
    params.gravity =  Gravity.RIGHT;
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

in maifest

```
 <activity android:name=".DialogAct"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

This is what my launcher activity looks like

[image]

So when i click on search on action bar i'm sending intent to my new activity .I want to make it look like pop just below the search icon 
This what i obtained is
[image]

You can see search of previous activity is clicked and new activity is loaded(blue portion). 
As you can see the new activity moves to centre of screen . but i want it just below the action bar icon.

i tried `params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;`. then i got this

[image]

I want to place it just below the action bar of previous activity . I tried many ways to achieve it but failed. so can anyone suggest a methode

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest you wrote

```
<activity android:name=".DialogAct"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
```

you should remove the `NoActionBar` part

```
<activity android:name=".DialogAct"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

Comment: if give so it will display title bar in my activity . i doesn't want to show that

Comment: but in your question you say you want it to below the action bar, how can you detect whether it is below action bar if you dont use an action bar?

Comment: well that's my problem the blue are in screen shot is an activity. with out title bar /action bar and what you seen  behind that is previous activity which navigate to the this activity .

Comment: i dont get you, you want actionbar or not ? and if you dont want, how it will be possible to position your popup below action bar? it makes no sense

Comment: what do you have when you try to remove params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two things that may help. First, you could try changing the `Theme` in your `manifest` to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog` and this should give you the wanted look.

**Edit**

You can hide the title bar with

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

just make sure to call it before calling `setContentView()`

Also, if it doesn't need to be a separate `Activity` you could use [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). With this you can use [isAboveAnchor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#isAboveAnchor%28%29) and use the `ActionBar` as the anchor and place it below or use one of the other associated methods. I don't know if either of these will fulfill what you need but they may work for you.

Comment: i try changing my theme but it doesn't help it bring out the title bar. that should be avoided in my case .I can't go for popover since there many fragment transactions are going to happening in my activity. so i need a full control over it. Thant's why i took this approach

Comment: If the title bar is your only problem with the first solution then see my edit. That will allow you to hide the title bar

Comment: I tried it .but still not able to achieve what i needed . can please check the edit .

Comment: Solved it in my own way creating custom theme. thanks for your guidance

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you solved it. If none of these answers helped you can post your own solution and accept it

Answer (score 0):

@edwin What you can do is  after making

```
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
```

you just provide some margin from top, like this:

```
  LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
  yourCustomPopOveractivity.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and i think after doing this you can get your needed position and everything you just did is right.

Please try then tell me

Comment: FIRST OF ALL THANKS FOR YOUR EFFORT .ACTUALLY I FOUND OUT SOLUTION FOR THIS AFTER POSTING THE QUESTION IN ANOTHER WAY THROUGH A SMALL WORKAROUND IN XML.

Comment: @edwin Oh great! you found the answer. So please provide your solution here and if my answer is also right and useful then please vote for answer or make answer accepted so that if anyone is facing the same problem can find the answer here. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try Gravity to Center rather than Top Right..

Comment: i want this to be on the right side of screen that's why i give that. If give centre it will move to the centre of screen

Comment: if yes then give top margin to params and see how it reacts??